# Can I use distinct on two fields in Korma?

Tags: korma

I have a table with four fields: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

I want a query like:

```
select distinct a, b from t;
```

The documentation suggests something like

```
(k/select my-table
          (k/modifier "DISTINCT")
          (k/fields :a :b))
```

But the generated SQL is like:

```
SELECT distinct a, b, c, d FROM my_table;
```

What I want is:

```
SELECT distinct a, b FROM my_table;
```

How do I restrict the distinct modifier to only two fields?

Experimenting with different modifier values (e.g. `DISTINCT (a, b)`) results in a mangled SQL Query.

Here's a complete example:

```
(k/defentity my-table (k/entity-fields :a :b :c :d))

(k/sql-only (k/select my-table (k/fields :a :b)
                               (k/modifier "DISTINCT")))

"SELECT DISTINCT `my-table`.`a`,
                 `my-table`.`b`,
                 `my-table`.`c`,
                 `my-table`.`d`,
                 `my-table`.`a`,
                 `my-table`.`b` FROM `my-table`"
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL keyword `DISTINCT` operates on the whole column in most (all?) databases, including MySQL and SQL Server.  Therefore, in at least those databases, there is no way to use `DISTINCT` on a subset of fields.

A different query, possible like those suggested in [SQL - 'DISTINCT' based on only some columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6792285/3108853) might get you what you need.

Comment: I don't want distinct on a subset of returned fields. I'll add the actual SQL I want in my question, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Does it generate the proper query when you remove the distinct modifier?  And what database engine are you querying against?

Comment: MySQL. You can see the repeated `a` and `b` from the query above. I think this is a bug/feature, discussed here: https://github.com/korma/Korma/issues/251

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Once you define columns on a model, Korma always returns all columns.